# How can I import xml into MarkLogic with namespaces that are defined in separate files?

Tags: xml, marklogic, dtd, mlcp

I have some XML containing namespaces that are defined in a DTD. When I try to import the xml using the MarkLogic Content Pump (MLCP), it fails, pointing at the undefined namespaces.

What is the easiest way to get this data imported?

We do have an XML catalog. Can I make ML aware of that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There may be a number of options for resolving the namespaces and/or repairing instance documents. https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/repair#id_82051 It would be easier to advise if you could provide more detail and a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

@Mads Hansen lead me in the right direction. It was a matter of using the [MLCP option](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_23879) `xml_repair_level`:

```
-xml_repair_level full
```